# Swing app login to gmail

Tags: java, email, oauth, gmail

I'm building a standalone swing application that connects to all modern mail services like Hotmail, Outlook, Gmail.

My case is:

1. Show to user small window like "enter you mail and pass"
2. Obtain all emails and show them to user

And this is place where problems started. All guidelines and tutorials send me to use OAuth protocol. It's not obvious to me and i really can't get where the user login+pass is. Also I can't use any other way to connect to gmail 'cause this is part of functionality (and what customer wants). How to make user connect to his mail without any interaction except entering mail and pass? 
Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is no longer the standard to us login and password.   Oauth is considered by many to be more secure.   You could look into connecting to these services using smtp or IMAP protocol i know that gmail at least still supports it i wouldn't be surprised if hotmail and outlook dont as well.

Comment: Does https://google.github.io/google-oauth-java-client/releases/1.21.0/javadoc/com/google/api/client/auth/oauth2/package-summary.html#package_description help?